# Reducing the .net framework by sharing the framework among all users

Tags: c#, .net

We have a WinForms application running on Citrix. Is it possible for all the different users running the application to share the .NET Framework so that each application does not need to load the framework when it starts up? Will using AppDomains do that for me? If I have 10 users running the same application on the Citrix server I really would like to scale the app better by not having the .NET Framework loaded 10 times.

Comment: The CLR is pretty smart about that. The GAC 
will allow for code sharing depending on how you structure your program.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That is true, but still every consuming process will load the same assembly from GAC separately from all other processes referencing the same assembly.

Comment: A .NET application only loads CLR and the assemblies it uses, but not the whole .NET Framework. However, if the application has been launched by 10 users, as 10 running processes, definitely CLR and those assemblies would be loaded 10 times. All other applications (C++/Java) do the same, and you should get used to that.

Answer (score 2):

An important element to understand when talking about `AppDomain`s is that the `AppDomain` is part of the process, not the other way around. One process can have multiple `AppDomain`s, but one `AppDomain` cannot be associated with more than one process.

Therefore, one possible answer would be to look for the ways in which multiple clients would access the same application instance. If that is not an option, then I don't see other ways for you to optimize processes.